# Creating a flexible bar chart with a complex dataset using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3. I'm following this great tutorial that makes a flexible chart which fills to the size of your width and height no matter how many bars are created. ('The new Chart').http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch06.html#_the_new_chart

I am having trouble using my own data. This is the the tutorials code to make a bar chart with a very simple data set:

```
        var w = 500;
        var h = 100;
        var barPadding = 1;

        var data = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
                        11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];

        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        svg.selectAll("rect")
           .data(data)
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return i * (w / data.length);
           })
           .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - (d * 4);
           })
           .attr("width", w / data.length - barPadding)
           .attr("height", function(d) {
                return d * 4;
           });
```

I think mine not working, has something to do with the data.length parts of the tutorials code:

```
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return i * (w / data.length);
```

Or it could be the way I am requesting 'time' from my data. This is my code:

```
  <div id="chart">
  <svg width="800" height="600"><g class="group"></g>
  </svg>
  </div>

  var w = 500;
  var h = 100;
  var barPadding = 1;

  var data = [
  {"name": "The Kings speech", "time": 118},
  {"name": "Slumdog Millionaire", "time": 120},
  {"name": "Shakespeare in Love", "time": 122},
  {"name": "Chariots of Fire", "time": 123},
  ]

  d3.select('svg g.group')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {return i * (w / data.length)})
  .attr('y', function(d) {return h - d['time'];})
  .attr('width', w / data.length - barPadding)
  .attr('height', function(d) {return d['time'];})
```

I know this will be simple to a lot of you, but I've spent too long on this and you'd be a great help getting me through this! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, semicolumn should be outside of `['time']`:

```
.attr('y', function(d) {return h - (d['time';])})
```

should be

```
.attr('y', function(d) {return h - d['time'];})
```

You should look at the error messages shown in the developer console to identify errors.

Edit after question update:

your javascript code should be wrapped around `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>`

Comment: Thank you so much! However it is still not working. I will update the question to remove those errors. Thanks

Comment: I have tried adding  

console.log(data);

to the end and when I view I get 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

I did some research on this and it could be an unclosed <script> tag etc but everything looks ok to me. Sorry, again, I'm a beginner

Comment: 1. is your code wrapped around <script> and </script> tags? doesn't look to be so in the code you pasted. 2. Next to uncaught syntax error, you have the file name and line number corresponding to the code that failed to run. This is what you should use to debug, and this is what you should include in your question.

Comment: Sorry for not adding the <script> in my code, was trying to keep the length of my question down. You are a gem, thanks so much for all this help.